# Windows (10) - switch between languages with CTRL SHIFT

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, language, input-languages

I'm working with Win 10 Pro 64-bit (clean installation, not upgrade), having it bi-lingual (English-Hebrew).

When I want to switch languages, I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> as usual and it's working fine. When pressing on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (right or left), the cursor aligns to the appropriate side of the text area to type in.

Usually, this action is supposed also to switch between the languages accordingly - <kbd>left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>aligns the cursor to the left and switches to English, and <kbd>right Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>aligns the cursor to the right and switches to Hebrew.

For some reason, this doesn't happen! When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, it only aligns the cursor, but doesn't switch the language.

I went over all the settings and definitions of language, region and so on, and didn't find a way to fix this.

Any help or advice on this annoying matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 different ways to work with language switching.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd> changes between actual languages. A language bar will change from EN to the other language.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd> will change between keyboard layouts.

In order for this to work, you need to add a second keyboard layout for a specific language. Do note, it may be that the keyboard layout has already been added but still it doesn't work. If so, remove and readd the keyboard layout.

I suspect a windows 10 update causing things to break at some point in the past.

Comment: The thing is that on my work laptop, this behavior is working fine. When I press CTRL-SHIFT, the appropriate language is changed and the cursor is aligned to the right side. I don't understand what is the difference between these two OSs and what I am missing here...
As for the solution you're suggesting here, I don't understand exactly what you mean by "add a second keyboard layout...", I already have two keyboards installed on the system - English and Hebrew, of course. What more do I need to install/setup??...

Comment: A keyboard layout is installed per language. So it is possible that your english layout has 2 keyboard layouts, but your hebrew one doesn't, and the one that doesn't won't have CTRL-SHIFT support.