# Windows 10: can't switch to third language

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

I have 5 keyboard layouts in total: English US, English Colemak, Russian, Japanese Microsoft IME, Japanese Google IME.

Today I've finally updated the system after a month or two of postponing it, and layout switching behaviour changed completely.

Before: pressing Ctrl+Shift changed language (to the last used layout), in my case it would cycle through **English Colemak** - **Russian** - **Japanese Google IME**.

Now: pressing Ctrl+Shift changes between **English US** and **Russian**. Japanese is skipped completely, and if I switch to **English US** with Ctrl+Shift, then switch to **English Colemak** with Alt+Shift, then switch to **Russian** with Ctrl+Shift, the next Ctrl+Shift will bring me back to **English US** layout.

I can't set Colemak as the default, as it is considered a "keyboard" inside the English US "language", and I can't delete the US layout (although I remember that at some point, maybe a year or more ago, I did exactly this, and it was restored with future update). I also can't delete Japanese Microsoft IME, as it is a "language", and Google IME is "keyboard" inside it.

So I'm forced to either cycle through 5 layouts with Win+Space, or switch twice to get to my preferred Colemak layout - with Japanese being unavailable through Ctrl+Shift.

How can I restore previous behaviour?

Comment: Strange. Ctrl+Shift since always changed keyboard layouts within the current language only ([link](https://superuser.com/questions/1162479/windows-10-switch-between-languages-with-ctrl-shift)). You must have had some application controlling the keyboard for you. Question: Which Windows version have you updated and to what?

Comment: Current OS Build is 19042.985, not sure what I updated from. Regarding Ctrl+Shift switching between the languages - might be that I swapped the shortcuts. Just tested it - Alt+Shift switches layouts within the language, Ctrl+Shift switches between languages, albeit only as described above.

Comment: Open *Settings > Time & Language > Language*. Below "Preferred languages", do you find a button labelled "Group related languages"? If yes, click it.

Comment: No, there's no button "Group related languages". However, I managed to make Colemak the default layout by _Settings > Time & Language > Language > Keyboard > Override for default input method_. Still can't choose Japanese, even by Alt + Space, it just selects Russian (the second choice). Removed/added Japanese, reinstalled Google IME, rebooted multiple times, still no joy.

Comment: I also tried adding Chinese and Spanish to the list of languages. They installed correctly, but I can't switch to them either, although they are present in the list when pressing Alt + Space.